# Convert a multidimensional javascript array to JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What is the best way of converting a multi-dimensional javascript array to JSON?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most of the popular JavaScript frameworks have JSON utility functions included. For instance, jQuery has a function that directly calls a url and loads the JSON result as an object : http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson

However, you can get an open-source JSON parser and stringifier from [the json website](http://www.json.org) :

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Then, simply include the code and use the JSON.stringify() method on your array.

Comment: Down-voted for answering a JavaScript question with a framework/library response. Browsers *already support JavaScript* so making a 10% effort to program the right way results in much greater than 10% performance. Plus with *real JavaScript* you won't have to rewrite code to use a newer version of a framework or library.

Comment: Just a note: "real" JavaScript (meaning: JavaScript copied from SO or coded on one's own) is not tested nor refined or optimized. You might not want the whole library, but you might want the function. Plus: frameworks like Svelte or others include this kind of library already. Reinventing the wheel is not always a good idea since the resulting quality is unknown.

Answer (score 15):

The "best" way has been provided by the other posters. If you don't need the full encoding features of the referenced libraries, and only need to encode simple arrays, then try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple functions for encoding Javascript arrays into JSON</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  var a = [
    [0, 1, '2', 3],
    ['0', '1', 2],
    [],
    ['mf', 'cb']
  ],
  b = [
    0, '1', '2', 3, 'woohoo!'
  ];
  alert(array2dToJson(a, 'a', '\n'));
  alert(array1dToJson(b, 'b'));
};

function array2dToJson(a, p, nl) {
  var i, j, s = '{"' + p + '":[';
  nl = nl || '';
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    s += nl + array1dToJson(a[i]);
    if (i < a.length - 1) {
      s += ',';
    }
  }
  s += nl + ']}';
  return s;
}

function array1dToJson(a, p) {
  var i, s = '[';
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof a[i] == 'string') {
      s += '"' + a[i] + '"';
    }
    else { // assume number type
      s += a[i];
    }
    if (i < a.length - 1) {
      s += ',';
    }
  }
  s += ']';
  if (p) {
    return '{"' + p + '":' + s + '}';
  }
  return s;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but if you are trying to convert the object into a string of JSON then you probably want to look at the native JSON support in all the new browsers.  Here's Resig's [post](http://ejohn.org/blog/the-state-of-json/) on it.  For browsers that don't yet support it try the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.  JSON.stringify(obj) will convert your object to a string of JSON.

Comment: Here's firefox's dev page on JSON support:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON#Using_JSON

Answer (score 1):

This will convert all combinations of arrays within objects and vice versa including function names:

```
function isArray(a){var g=a.constructor.toString();
   if(g.match(/function Array()/)){return true;}else{return false;}
}
function objtostring(o){var a,k,f,freg=[],txt; if(typeof o!='object'){return false;}
   if(isArray(o)){a={'t1':'[','t2':']','isarray':true}
   }else         {a={'t1':'{','t2':'}','isarray':false}}; txt=a.t1;
   for(k in o){
           if(!a.isarray)txt+="'"+k+"':";
           if(typeof o[k]=='string'){txt+="'"+o[k]+"',";
           }else if(typeof o[k]=='number'||typeof o[k]=='boolean'){txt+=o[k]+",";
           }else if(typeof o[k]=='function'){f=o[k].toString();freg=f.match(/^function\s+(\w+)\s*\(/);
               if(freg){txt+=freg[1]+",";}else{txt+=f+",";};
           }else if(typeof o[k]=='object'){txt+=objtostring(o[k])+",";
           }
   }return txt.substr(0,txt.length-1)+a.t2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the encode function of [this library](http://www.devpro.it/JSON/files/JSON-js.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a bit the code previously provided... because a JSON has this format: `[{"object":{"property_1":"value_1","property_2":"value_2"}}]`

So, the code would be...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple functions for encoding Javascript arrays into JSON</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
      var a = [['property_1','value_1'],['property_2', 'value_2']];
      alert("Comienzo..., paso ////"+a+"\\\\\\ a formato JSON");
      var jsonSerialized = array2dToJson(a, 'object');
      alert(jsonSerialized);
    };

    // Estructura de JSON [{"object":{"property_1":"value_1","property_2":"value_2"}}]

    function array2dToJson(a, p, nl) {
      var i, j, s = '[{"' + p + '":{';
      nl = nl || '';
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        s += nl + array1dToJson(a[i]);
        if (i < a.length - 1) {
          s += ',';
        }
      }
      s += nl + '}}]';
      return s;
    }

    function array1dToJson(a, p) {
      var i, s = '';
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof a[i] == 'string') {
          s += '"' + a[i] + '"';
        }
        else { // assume number type
          s += a[i];
        }
        if (i < a.length - 1) {
          s += ':';
        }
      }
      s += '';
      if (p) {
        return '{"' + p + '":' + s + '}';
      }
      return s;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Convertir un Array a JSON...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = {}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var _main = {};
    var _dis = {}
    var _check = {};

    _main["title"] = 'test';
    _main["category"] = 'testing';
    _dis[0] = '';
    _dis[1] = '';
    _dis[2] = '';
    _dis[3] = '';
    _check[0] = 'checked';
    _check[1] = 'checked';
    _check[2] = 'checked';
    _check[3] = 'checked';
    _main['values'] = _check;
    _main['disabled'] = _dis;
    t[i] = _main;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(t));
```

Try this

Comment: Output of this code is  {"0":{"title":"Contributory","category":"Plan Features","values":{"0":"checked","1":"checked","2":"checked","3":"checked"},"disabled":{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":""}},"1":{"title":"Contributory","category":"Plan Features","values":{"0":"checked","1":"checked","2":"checked","3":"checked"},"disabled":{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":""}},"2":{"title":"Contributory","category":"Plan Features","values":{"0":"checked","1":"checked","2":"checked","3":"checked"},"disabled":{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":""}}}

Answer (score 0):

use this code and very simple develop for more two array

```
function getJSON(arrayID,arrayText) {    
    var JSON = "[";
    //should arrayID length equal arrayText lenght and both against null
    if (arrayID != null && arrayText != null && arrayID.length == arrayText.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
            JSON += "{";
            JSON += "text:'" + arrayText[i] + "',";
            JSON += "id:'" + arrayID[i] + "'";
            JSON += "},";
        }
    }
    JSON += "]"
    JSON = Function("return " + JSON + " ;");
    return JSON();
}
```

and 3 array

```
function getJSON(arrayID, arrayText, arrayNumber) {
    var JSON = "[";  
    if (arrayID != null && arrayText != null && arrayNumber!=null && Math.min(arrayNumber.length,arrayID.length)==arrayText.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
            JSON += "{";
            JSON += "text:'" + arrayText[i] + "',";
            JSON += "id:'" + arrayID[i] + "',";
            JSON += "number:'" + arrayNumber[i] + "'";
            JSON += "},";
        }
    }
    JSON += "]"
    JSON = Function("return " + JSON + " ;");
    return JSON();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript will correctly encode an object:

```
var a = new Object;
var a = {};
```

JavaScript will *not* encode an *array*:

```
var a = new Array();
var a = [];
```