# How to convert a Javascript Array of Arrays into a JSON String

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a complicated example of converting a Javascript Array to a JSON String.

Let's say I have two type of objects. The first type is called a Property, it has the fields: id, uri, label and values[] where values is an array of the second type of object.

The second type of object, called a Value has the fields: id, uri, label.

If I had a simple Array I believe I would do: var arrayAsJSON = myarray.stringify(); Would this work in this case. I have tried it and it comes back as undefined, but perhaps I am doing some else wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a multidimensional javascript array to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459105/convert-a-multidimensional-javascript-array-to-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common you can use JSON.stringify(array), but not all browsers have this method implemented. However if you use some JS framework stringify is probably implemented there for old browsers.

Comment: I feel pretty safe in admitting that's one of my stupidest mistakes .... thanks though :)

Comment: Don't blame yourself. Sometimes it's better to ask then spent the whole day in unsuccessful attempts.