# Convert Array of Arrays into JSON

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have an array of arrays that I'd like to convert into json and output within another array. I have the following array:

```
weekdays = [["Monday",2],["Tuesday",4],["Thursday",5]]
```

I would like to include this array within a JSON output like so:

```
json_output = { :results => weekdays.count, :data => weekdays }
```

Right now I get this, which just doesn't look right as there are not curly brackets around the "data" field...

```
{
    "results": 2,
    "data": [
        ["Monday", 2],
        ["Tuesday", 4],
        ["Thursday", 5]
    ]
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe this [How to convert a Javascript Array of Arrays into a JSON String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224526/how-to-convert-a-javascript-array-of-arrays-into-a-json-string) is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct. Curly brackets are around hashes, but your data attribute is a nested array.

If you want to convert a nested array into a hash, just call [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) on it:

```
{ :results => weekdays.count, :data => weekdays.to_h }
```

Comment: ahh, so if i want it to like like most JSON does, I'll need to convert it into a hash first and assign keys - then I can include it as above?

Comment: super helpful, wow - thanks! related comment, should I want to include labels for each of the elements within "data" do i need to create a hash instead of an array?

Comment: Yes, working with a hash makes it much easier to add more attibutes.

Comment: @Brandon if your data is organized as key-value pairs, you should not use an array in the first place. That's what hashes are for.

Answer (score 1):

Better to convert it to hash manually.

```
weekdays = [["Monday",2],["Tuesday",4],["Thursday",5]]

hash_weekdays = Hash.new
weekdays.each do |item|
 hash_weekdays[item[0]] = item[1]
end

hash_weekdays #=> {"Monday"=>2, "Tuesday"=>4, "Thursday"=>5}
```