# JSON.stringify doesn't work with normal JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, json

I must be missing something here, but the following code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLjLY/)) returns an empty string:

```js
var test = new Array();
test['a'] = 'test';
test['b'] = 'test b';
var json = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(json);
```

What is the correct way of stringifying this array?

Comment: That's not an array, you are just setting two properties

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json)

Comment: Start out with `var test = {};` instead

Answer (score 136, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are designed to hold data with *numeric* indexes. You can add named properties to them because [an array is a type of object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874237/19068) (and this can be useful when you want to store metadata about an array which holds normal, ordered, numerically indexed data), but that isn't what they are designed for.

The JSON array data type *cannot* have named keys on an array.

When you pass a JavaScript array to `JSON.stringify` the named properties will be ignored.

If you want named properties, use an Object, not an Array.

```js
const test = {}; // Object
test.a = 'test';
test.b = []; // Array
test.b.push('item');
test.b.push('item2');
test.b.push('item3');
test.b.item4 = "A value"; // Ignored by JSON.stringify
const json = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: But if I use an Object, it doesn't have the array prototypes like splice.

Comment: @Michael — Maybe you should ask a new question in which you explain your problem that for some reason requires that you splice on something with named properties that you need to stringify to JSON.

Answer (score 13):

Nice explanation and example above. I found this ([JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-bizarreness)) to complete the answer. Some sites implements  its own toJSON with JSONFilters, so delete it.

```
if(window.Prototype) {
    delete Object.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Hash.prototype.toJSON;
    delete String.prototype.toJSON;
}
```

it works fine and the output of the test:

```
console.log(json);
```

Result:

```
"{"a":"test","b":["item","item2","item3"]}"
```

Comment: I had some issues with a site that overwrite Date, so when I use the Date.toJSON fails I so I added: Date.prototype.toJSON = Date.prototype.toISOString;

Answer (score 6):

I posted a fix for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728537/2016196)

You can use this function to modify `JSON.stringify` to encode `arrays`, just post it near the beginning of your script (check the link above for more detail):

```
// Upgrade for JSON.stringify, updated to allow arrays
(function(){
    // Convert array to object
    var convArrToObj = function(array){
        var thisEleObj = new Object();
        if(typeof array == "object"){
            for(var i in array){
                var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
                thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
            }
        }else {
            thisEleObj = array;
        }
        return thisEleObj;
    };
    var oldJSONStringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function(input){
        if(oldJSONStringify(input) == '[]')
            return oldJSONStringify(convArrToObj(input));
        else
            return oldJSONStringify(input);
    };
})();
```

Comment: this is a nice start, but it's making some assumptions, for instance, that the array doesn' t have any indexed values.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is the [`JSON.stringify()` replacer function param](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/stringify#replacer-function). You can pass a 2nd arg to `JSON.stringify()` that has special handling for empty arrays as shown below.

```js
const arr = new Array();
arr.answer = 42;

// {"hello":"world","arr":{"answer":42}}
JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world', arr }, function replacer(key, value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
    return { ...value }; // Converts empty array with string properties into a POJO
  }
  return value;
});
```

Comment: I don't understand setting arr.answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use like this

```
var test = new Array();
test[0]={};
test[0]['a'] = 'test';
test[1]={};
test[1]['b'] = 'test b';
var json = JSON.stringify(test);
alert(json);
```

Like this you JSON-ing a array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **JavaScript arrays** are *not* *associative* like php-arrays, they are designed to hold data with *numeric* indexes. But I understand what you want. JavaScript arrays can contain both object properties (like "string indexes") and numbers in strings (like "number indexes"). You can stringify/serialize it only to plain JavaScript object `{"key1": value1, "key2": value2, ...}`.

E.g. you want stringify an array `a`, but avoid null/undefined in output (for clarity question is extended):

```js
a = []; // new Array();
a[0] = "UK";
a[1] = 7;
a["5"] = 8;
a["32"] = 77;
a[7] = 0;
a["8"] = NaN;
a[9] = undefined;
a["10"] = null;
a[11] = {};
a["19"] = false;
a[20] = true;
a['A'] = 'test';
a['B'] = 'test B';
a.push('wonderland');
a.push(98);
a[4294967294] = 42;
delete a[4294967294];
```

```
(4294967295) ['UK', 7, empty × 3, 8, empty, 0, NaN, undefined, null, {…}, empty × 7, false, true, empty × 11, 77, 'wonderland', 98, empty × 4294967260, A: 'test', B: 'test B']
```

```js
a.length
4294967295
```

So even `JSON.stringify(a)` could be possible, it will be finished with many nulls (and without 'A', 'B')...

```
'["UK",7,null,null,null,8,null,0,null,null,null,{},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,false,true,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,77,"wonderland",98,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,...
```

We can fix it with Object.assign!

```js
function replacer (key, value) {
  return (!!value || value === false || value === '' || typeof value === 'number') ? value : undefined;
}

JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, a), replacer)
```

**Or even simpler**:

```js
JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, a))
```

```
'{"0":"UK","1":7,"5":8,"7":0,"8":null,"10":null,"11":{},"19":false,"20":true,"32":77,"33":"wonderland","34":98,"A":"test","B":"test B"}'
```

Back conversion to array is harder:

```js
jsonObj = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, a));
aObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj)

b = []
Object.entries(aObj).forEach(entry => b[entry[0]] = entry[1])
console.log(b)
```

```
(35) ['UK', 7, empty × 3, 8, empty, 0, null, empty, null, {…}, empty × 7, false, true, empty × 11, 77, 'wonderland', 98, A: 'test', B: 'test B']
```

P. S. 1: You can also see, that we filtered null/undefined for extremely long source array (sparse array) `a`, which was impossible with array.filter.

P. S. 2: But for our specific task, we can not use `JSON.stringify(Object.assign([], a))`, because we do not want to miss `a['A'] = 'test'; a['B'] = 'test B'`.

P. S. 3: To avoid using such unintuitive things, you must use Plain Object `{}` or better `Map`.

Answer (score -7):

Json has to have key-value pairs. Tho you can still have an array as the value part. Thus add a "key" of your chousing:

var json = JSON.stringify({whatver: test});

Comment: This is just wrong. `JSON.stringify([15,12])` will work. It will give `"[15,12]"`