# Convert JavaScript object or array to JSON for ajax data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

So I'm creating an array with element information. I loop through all elements and save the index. For some reason I cannot convert this array to JSON!

This is my array loop:

```
var display = Array();
$('.thread_child').each(function(index, value){
   display[index]="none";
   if($(this).is(":visible")){
      display[index]="block";
   }
});
```

I try to turn it into JSON by:

```
data = JSON.stringify(display);
```

It doesn't seem to send the proper JSON format!

If I hand code it like this, it works and sends information:

```
data = {"0":"none","1":"block","2":"none","3":"block","4":"block","5":"block","6":"block","7":"block","8":"block","9":"block","10":"block","11":"block","12":"block","13":"block","14":"block","15":"block","16":"block","17":"block","18":"block","19":"block"};
```

When I do an alert on the JSON.stringify object it looks the same as the hand coded one. But it doesn't work.

I'm going crazy trying to solve this! What am I missing here? What's the best way to send this information to get the hand coded format?

I am using this ajax method to send data:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data:data,
        url: "myfile.php",
        cache: false,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(rsp) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(rsp));
        var Content = rsp;
        var Template = render('tsk_lst');
        var HTML = Template({ Content : Content });
        $( "#task_lists" ).html( HTML );
        }
    });
```

Using GET method because I'm displaying information (not updating or inserting). Only sending display info to my PHP file.

---

END SOLUTION

---

```
var display = {};
$('.thread_child').each(function(index, value){
   display[index]="none";
   if($(this).is(":visible")){
      display[index]="block";
   }
});

$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: display,
        url: "myfile.php",
        cache: false,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(rsp) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(rsp));
        var Content = rsp;
        var Template = render('tsk_lst');
        var HTML = Template({ Content : Content });
        $( "#task_lists" ).html( HTML );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Console.log the your data var. 

data = JSON.stringify(display);
console.log(data);

And see what you are getting.

Comment: Simply don't convert the data.

Comment: ["block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block","block"]

Its missing the numbers.. "0":"block","1":"block"...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but I think you are probably surprised at how arrays are serialized in JSON. Let's isolate the problem. Consider following code:

```
var display = Array();
display[0] = "none";
display[1] = "block";
display[2] = "none";

console.log( JSON.stringify(display) );
```

This will print:

```
["none","block","none"]
```

This is how JSON actually serializes array. However what you want to see is something like:

```
{"0":"none","1":"block","2":"none"}
```

To get this format you want to serialize object, not array. So let's rewrite above code like this:

```
var display2 = {};
display2["0"] = "none";
display2["1"] = "block";
display2["2"] = "none";

console.log( JSON.stringify(display2) );
```

This will print in the format you want.

You can play around with this here: http://jsbin.com/oDuhINAG/1/edit?js,console

Comment: So you do all this.. then you don't convert anything! 
data: display2,
dataType: "json"
and it all works

Comment: When you work with objectw and have numeric index, then you don't have to put them in quotes. i.e. `display2[0] = "none"` is enough

Comment: What if you want to build a list of objects - i.e. `var list = [ { id: 1, status: "good" }, { id: 2, status: "Bad" } ]` - and pass them to the controller action as an IEnumerable list of Model type with id and status attributes? my list is not being filled.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `JSON.stringify(object)` with an object and I just wrote a function that'll recursively convert an array to an object, like this `JSON.stringify(convArrToObj(array))`, which is the following code (more detail can be found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728420/2016196)):

```
// Convert array to object
var convArrToObj = function(array){
    var thisEleObj = new Object();
    if(typeof array == "object"){
        for(var i in array){
            var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
            thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
        }
    }else {
        thisEleObj = array;
    }
    return thisEleObj;
}
```

To make it more generic, you can override the `JSON.stringify` function and you won't have to worry about it again, to do this, just paste this at the top of your page:

```
// Modify JSON.stringify to allow recursive and single-level arrays
(function(){
    // Convert array to object
    var convArrToObj = function(array){
        var thisEleObj = new Object();
        if(typeof array == "object"){
            for(var i in array){
                var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
                thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
            }
        }else {
            thisEleObj = array;
        }
        return thisEleObj;
    };
    var oldJSONStringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function(input){
        return oldJSONStringify(convArrToObj(input));
    };
})();
```

And now `JSON.stringify` will accept `arrays` or `objects`! ([link to jsFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/TWbhA/))

---

Edit:

Here's another version that's a tad bit more efficient, although it may or may not be less reliable (not sure -- it depends on if `JSON.stringify(array)` *always* returns `[]`, which I don't see much reason why it wouldn't, so this function should be better as it does a little less work when you use `JSON.stringify` with an `object`):

```
(function(){
    // Convert array to object
    var convArrToObj = function(array){
        var thisEleObj = new Object();
        if(typeof array == "object"){
            for(var i in array){
                var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
                thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
            }
        }else {
            thisEleObj = array;
        }
        return thisEleObj;
    };
    var oldJSONStringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function(input){
        if(oldJSONStringify(input) == '[]')
            return oldJSONStringify(convArrToObj(input));
        else
            return oldJSONStringify(input);
    };
})();
```

[jsFiddle with example here](http://jsfiddle.net/TWbhA/1/)

[js Performance test here, via jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/json-stringify-updated2)