# use value of variable instead of variable in getJSON function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send a variable to server with getJSON function in jquery.

```
y = "some data";
if (con == true) {
    t = "brand";
}
else {
    t = "type";
}
$.getJSON('url', { t: y }).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

in the server side i have function for each information that send with getJSON. for example when i use `brand` instead of `t` , the `brand()` function in the server side called and when i send `type` instead of `t` , `type()` function in the server side called.
`t` variable is different in some case.for example the value of `t` variable in one case is equal to `brand` and in another case is equal to `type` .how i can use value of `t` ,instead of `t` in this case?

Comment: See this :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data

Comment: Obviously it would be better if you send something like: `{ method: brand, data: data};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @u_mulder, it would be better to have the data being sent to the server in a well defined structure, so your getJSON call would look like

```
$.getJSON('url', { method: t, data: y }).done(function (data) {...});
```

If you are bent on using the structure you have mentioned you will have to do something like

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[t] = y;

$.getJSON('url', dataObj).done(function (data) {...});
```

This way the value of `t` will be populated as a property under the `dataObj` object. So the `dataObj` value will be equivalent to `{ brand: "some data" }` or `{ type: "some data" }` depending on the branch that is executed.