# jQuery cookie plugin doesn't read or write cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am trying to use the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) but it doesn't seem to be reading or writing my data:

```
var cookieArray = [];
cookieArray['test'] = true;
console.log(cookieArray);

$.cookie('testing', cookieArray, { expires: 10 });
console.log($.cookie('testing') + "hi");
```

The last log is always just "hi" - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/rfFRV/1/)

I was wondering if there was anything I wasn't including or doing correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declare differently for object array to store them  i.e `{}` it will make them as Object , but i used to JSON.stringify the array and save them for better manipulation.

```
var cookieArray = {};
cookieArray['test'] = true;
console.log(cookieArray);
$.cookie('testing', JSON.stringify(cookieArray), { expires: 10 });
console.log($.cookie('testing') + "hi");
```

for these way of doing explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data). [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyaraj888/rfFRV/7/)

Comment: hahaha, I had just worked out I was declaring the wrong type of array and was about to post my own answer - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/rfFRV/9/