# Convert jquery array to json and send it through ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I have an array Like

```
info['mk'] = 'hi';
info['pk'] = 'hello';
info['wk'] = 'hi';
info['rk'] = 'hello';
```

And i want to convert in json and send through ajax .

Comment: what have you ever tried?

Comment: i have tried 
var arraywhole = JSON.stringify(info);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data

Comment: And as a reminder, `JSON.stringify()` does not work on all browsers. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Ok i`ll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
info = {}; //must be set 
info['mk'] = 'hi';
info['pk'] = 'hello';
info['wk'] = 'hi';
info['rk'] = 'hello';
```

then `JSON.stringify(info);`

Comment: You should explain `JSON.stringify()` only works on **Object**, not **Array**.

Comment: Yes Raptor,Now i got it that JSON.stringify() only works on Object, not Array, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
info={}
info['mk'] = 'hi';
info['pk'] = 'hello';
info['wk'] = 'hi';
info['rk'] = 'hello';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({info:info}),
  url: "",
  success: function(msg){

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "target",
        data: info
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
var info = [];
var tmpObj = {};
info['mk'] = 'hi';
info['pk'] = 'hello';
info['wk'] = 'hi';
info['rk'] = 'hello';
tmpObj.arr = info;
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "target",
    datatype:"json",
    data: tmpObj
});
```