# Convert a javascript array to specific json format

Tags: json

I have this JSON.stringify(array) result: ["id:1x,price:150","id:2x,price:200"] and I have to convert it in a json format similar to this (it would be sent to php): 
[{
"id":"1x",
"price":150
},
{
"id":"2x",
"price":200
}]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the structure of your data before using `JSON.stringify`, for example you can convert the data to a list of objects like so:

```
var strItems =  ["id:1x,price:150", "id:2x,price:200"];
var objItems = [];

for (var i = 0; i < strItems.length; i++) {
    var pairs = strItems[i].split(","); 
    objItems.push({
        id: pairs[0].split(':')[1],
        price: parseInt(pairs[1].split(':')[1])
        });
}
```

Before calling `JSON.stringify` to get the result you're after:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(objItems);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify(array) only does on layer, but you can change the stringify function to work for multiple layers with this function written by JVE999 on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data):

```
(function(){
    // Convert array to object
    var convArrToObj = function(array){
        var thisEleObj = new Object();
        if(typeof array == "object"){
            for(var i in array){
                var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
                thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
            }
        }else {
            thisEleObj = array;
        }
        return thisEleObj;
    };
    var oldJSONStringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function(input){
        if(oldJSONStringify(input) == '[]')
            return oldJSONStringify(convArrToObj(input));
        else
            return oldJSONStringify(input);
    };
})();
```

Once you have declared this, then you can call JSON.stringify(array)