# How to write data in JSON or CSV?

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv, graph

I am currently making a table which shows data in a bar graph and used data arrays until this point as a means for the bars. I have reached a point where I would like to externalise this data (which I already know how to) however I have no clue at all how I would go about converting these data arrays into external .JSON or even CSV format.

Here is my code currently:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta>
  <meta name="description" content="Bar Graph Showing the Amount of Resources Being Used per Project " />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Resources per Program</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      font-size: 35px;
      color: darkblue;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      border-bottom-width: 3px;
      border-bottom-style: dashed;
      border-bottom-color: black;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: darkred;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      margin-left: 900px;
      margin-top: -40px; 
      margin-bottom: 70px
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 13px;
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .label {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: darkgrey;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      border-bottom-width: 3px;
      border-bottom-style: dashed;
      border-bottom-color: black;
    }

    html {
      background: linear-gradient(white, #a6a6a6);
    }

    .legend {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 17px; 
      font-weight: normal; 

    }   

     #myTooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: left;
      width: 150px;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 20px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background-color: rgb(102, 178, 255);
      border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 204);
      color: #5E99BD;
      border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
      padding: 11px;
     }

     #myTooltip:before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 204);
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      top: 100%;
      left: -2px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resources used per Program</h1>

  <p>Choose Month:
    <select id="label-option">
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
      <option value="June">June</option>
      <option value="July">July</option>
      <option value="August">August</option>
      <option value="September">September</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <h3>*Hold down the Selector and Drag onto Desired Option* (Touch Screen Users)</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var width = 1700
      var height = 500
      var emptyVar = 0
      var dataArrayProjects = ['2G', 'AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF', 'FG', 'GH']
      var April = [2.5, 2.1, 1.3, 15.2, 1, 4, 1, 4]
      var May = [2.5, 2.1, 1, 14.8, 1, 4, 2, 6]
      var June = [2.5, 2.1, 1, 14.8, 1, 4, 2, 6]
      var July = [2.5, 3.4, 2, 14.8, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 6]
      var August = [2.5, 3.4, 2.5, 14.8, 1.2, 3.5, 2.15, 6]
      var September = [2.5, 3, 2, 13.5, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 6]

      var clicked = true;

      d3.select("#label-option").on("change", change)

      function change() {
        var data = April;
        if (this.selectedIndex == 1){
          data = May;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 2){
          data = June;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 3){
          data = July;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 4){
          data = August;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 5){
          data = September;
        }
        canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)                  
        .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)
        .attr("width", emptyVar)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color[i%8] 
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * 55
        })

       bars.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .delay(200)
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d);
        });

        texts = canvas.selectAll(".label")
        .data(data)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d) + 10;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color[i%8] 
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return (i * 55) + 25
        })
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .text(function(d, i) {
          return d;
        }) 

        texts.transition()
        .duration(1800)
        .delay(180)
        .style("opacity", 1)  
      }

      var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 16])
        .range([0, width - 60]);

      var heightScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(dataArrayProjects)
        .rangePoints([10, height - 85]);

      var color = ["#1F45FC", "#87AFC7", "#87AFC7", "#151B54", "#1F45FC", "#151B54", "#1F45FC", "#151B54"]

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .ticks("20")
        .scale(widthScale);

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(heightScale)
        .orient("left");

      var canvas = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + 250)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(130, 0)");

      var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
          .data(April)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)                  
        .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)
          .attr("width", emptyVar)
          .attr("height", 50)
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return color[i%8] 
          })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return i * 55
          })

      var texts = canvas.selectAll(".label")
          .data(April)
           .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return widthScale(d) + 10;
            })
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color[i%8] 
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
              return (i * 55) + 25
            })
            .text(function(d, i) {
              return d;
            })
            .style("opacity", 0)

      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 430)")
        .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .call(xAxis);

      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      bars.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .delay(200)
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d);
        })

      texts.transition()
        .duration(1800)
        .delay(180)
        .style("opacity", 1)

      var yAxisLine = canvas.append("line")
                        .attr("x1", -3)
                        .attr("y1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", -3)
                        .attr("y2", 436)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 6)
                        .attr("stroke", "black");

      var legend = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", 450)
            .attr("height", 300)
            .attr("x", 1000)
            .attr("y", 0)

      legend.append("text")
              .text("All Projects")
              .attr("fill", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .attr("x", 1300)
              .attr("y", 20)
      legend.append("text")
              .text("All Core Capabilities")
              .attr("fill", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .attr("x", 1300)
              .attr("y", 50)
      legend.append("text")
              .text("Projects and Core Capabilities")
              .attr("fill", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .attr("x", 1300)
              .attr("y", 80)
      legend.append("text")
              .text("Click Circles to Highlight Corresponding Bar")
              .attr("fill", "darkred")
              .attr("font-size", 8.5)
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .attr("x", 1323)
              .attr("y", 110)

      legend.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 8)
              .attr("fill", "#1F45FC")
              .attr("cx", 1275)
              .attr("cy", 14.5)
              .on("click", function(){
                var rects = d3.selectAll("rect").filter(function(){
                return this.attributes.fill.nodeValue == "#1F45FC";
                });
                (clicked) ? rects.attr("stroke", "limegreen").attr("stroke-width", 3) : rects.attr("stroke-width", 0);
                clicked = !clicked;
              });

      legend.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 8)
              .attr("fill", "#87AFC7")
              .attr("cx", 1275)
              .attr("cy", 44.5)
              .on("click", function(){
                var rects = d3.selectAll("rect").filter(function(){
                return this.attributes.fill.nodeValue == "#87AFC7";
                });
                (clicked) ? rects.attr("stroke", "limegreen").attr("stroke-width", 3) : rects.attr("stroke-width", 0);
                 clicked = !clicked;
              });

      legend.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 8)
              .attr("fill", "#151B54")
              .attr("cx", 1275)
              .attr("cy", 74.5)
              .on("click", function(){
                var rects = d3.selectAll("rect").filter(function(){
                return this.attributes.fill.nodeValue == "#151B54";
                });
                (clicked) ? rects.attr("stroke", "limegreen").attr("stroke-width", 3) : rects.attr("stroke-width", 0);
                 clicked = !clicked;
              });

      var tooplTipDiv = d3.select("body").append("div")   
                      .attr("id", "myTooltip")               
                      .style("opacity", 0);

      function onMouseOver(d){

          var tooltipDiv = d3.select("#myTooltip"); 

          tooltipDiv.transition()        
             .duration(200)      
             .style("opacity", 1);    

          tooltipDiv.html( "Click for Resource Allocation over 6 Months")
             .style("left", (parseFloat(widthScale(d))) + "px") 
             .style("cursor", "pointer")
             .style("top", function(d){
                 return d3.event.pageY - this.offsetHeight - 17  + "px"
              })
              .style("color", "#333333");        
      }

      function onMouseOut(d){
          var tooltipDiv = d3.select("#myTooltip"); 
          tooltipDiv.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);  
      }

    </script>
    <h2>Resources</h2>  
</body>
</html>
```

Please ignore the tooltips as they are being worked on currently. What I would like to know is how I can extract the data arrays used in the code (e.g. April-September and dataArrayProjects), convert them to .JSON or CSV and still make sure the graph works the way I would like it to. Please make sure that the selector still works as the changing data based on month is a core part of the table.

Comment: You can convert any javascript object, including arrays, to json by simply using the JSON.stringify(object) method, it should work for most modern browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start simple by creating an object that contains some of the main parts of the data

```
var data = {
  projects: ['2G', 'AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF', 'FG', 'GH'],
  months: {
    April: [2.5, 2.1, 1.3, 15.2, 1, 4, 1, 4],
    May : [2.5, 2.1, 1, 14.8, 1, 4, 2, 6],
    //......
    September : [2.5, 3, 2, 13.5, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 6]
  }

}
```

Now instead of using variable `April` use `data.months.April` and for `dataArrayProjects` use `data.projects`

As you get various parts working add more of the other hard code variables to the object.

When you have that working start looking at ways to loop over `data.months` to do what you need in chart without code duplication and using dynamic properties and values.

Then  finally convert it all to json which is a simple step

The months might be easier as an array also. You will know better as you fine tune the data structure and loops in your code.

```
months: [ 
     {month:'April', data: [2.5, 2.1, 1.3, 15.2, 1, 4, 1, 4]},
     {month: 'September', data: [2.5, 3, 2, 13.5, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 6]}
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Perfect answer. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah...you just can't eat an elephant all in one bite

Answer (score 1):

Json is a format that stores information as JavaScript source code in plaintext files, (Javascript Object Notation)

Here’s an example of data formatted as JSON:

{"name": "Zophie", "isCat": true,
 "miceCaught": 0, "napsTaken": 37.5,
 "felineIQ": null}
more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970301/convert-javascript-object-or-array-to-json-for-ajax-data)

Comment: Not really true that json stores javascript source code, or that it has to be in files. It is simply a string data transfer format and can be used in most any language

Answer (score 0):

Json syntax should follow some rules like:

1.Data is in name/value pairs

2.Data is separated by commas

3.Curly braces hold objects

4.Square brackets hold arrays

```
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
];
```