# How to stringify array-like object to a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I use the somewhat infamous array-like objects in my Javascript code. `typeof` such an object is `"object"`, obviously, but it only has numerical properties (ie. indicies) + a `length` property + a `splice()` method. Thanks to this Chromium's & Firefox's console display these as if they were arrays.

`JSON.stringify()` is having none of that, though, and simply outputs a JSON object with the indicies as strings. Is there a way to make `JSON.stringify()` think my array-like objects are arrays?

Comment: How are you storing those objects? What is the format? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196338/json-stringify-doesnt-work-with-normal-javascript-array

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(theArrayThingy, 0))`?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yeah, I could do that, those object are exposed to the user, however, so idealy I'd like them to be stringified correctly directly...

Comment: You can add your own toJSON method, that'll be used by JSON.stringify

Comment: @LJ_1102 Brilliant, thanks! You can make that into an answer and I'll acceept it...

Comment: @LJ_1102 Nice, didn't know about that!

Comment: Alternatively `'[' + Array.prototype.map.call(arrayObject, JSON.stringify).join(',') + ']'`