# How can i print JSON with console.log

Tags: ajax, reactjs, typescript

I am writing a program with `php` `laravel` and `react.js`. But i am very new to these. Anyway in `react`, i am sending a API request with `ajax`.

like this:

```
const sendquery = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": url,
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + tkid,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": query
};

$.ajax(sendquery).done(function (response) {
    console.log('Survey Request :' + response);
});
```

There are another API requests that are printing nicely when i `console.log()` because they are in array type. But this must be `json`. I tested API with **Postman** everything is OK. But still i have output like this:

```
Survey Request :[object Object]
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Have you tried with `JSON.stringify(response)`?

Comment: write this as an answer pls so i can mark.

Comment: better approach is this noo need to stringify console.log('Survey Request', response);

Comment: pass your sting as first argument and the object as second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `JSON.stringify(response)` but note that it doesn't work with all the types, see [JSON.stringify doesn't work with normal Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196338/json-stringify-doesnt-work-with-normal-javascript-array), for example.

Answer (score 2):

To get json

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

To get structured JSON

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option apart from what @Beris Demiray wrote is to write:

`console.log('Survey Request :', response);`

Meaning to put the object as a second parameter in the log.

This will give you an object that you'll can open in the debugger.
The reason why this option is better because JSON.stringify doesn't stringify all objects, and this lets you look into all objects.

Comment: Thats exactly my answer, you have not contributed anything new

Comment: only post answers if you are either adding something new to existing answer or giving something completely new.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier we answered it more or less the same time when answered I didn't have in my view your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **JSON.parse** function like as below:

```
JSON.parse(response, null, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

use console.dir(object:any) like this ->

```
$.ajax(sendquery).done(function (response) {
    console.dir(response);
});
```

Comment: when i write this way "console.dir('Survey Request :' +response)" it doesnt work but  this is "console.dir(response)" working.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is pass the display string in the first argument and the object as second

```
 console.log('Survey Request', response);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While i acknowledge all answers above, it's important to point out why you seem to be getting that result on the console.

When you do this:

```
console.log('Survey Request :' + response);
```

You are basically trying to concatenate a primitive value `'Survey Reguest :'` with a complex value `response`, which is an object. Javascript cannot convert an object `response` to a primitive value. By simply replacing the `+` with a `,` signifies that you are sending the `response` object as a separate argument. Javascript then logs the arguments separately to the console.