# redux - async storage with associative array

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-redux, associative-array

I am trying to use **associative arrays with redux and to store them in the async storage** to retrieve on loading the app.

With redux it works very well I have real quick access to the values and can map the content very well into cards in the react native app.

Now when I store the data in async storage I have to JSON.stringify the content and JSON.parse it back on loading. Unfortunately somehow I cannot use the object the same way afterwards.

my data looks like this:

> ['1442-3338': { ID: '1442-3338', something: 'something',
> Participants: [] },   '1442-3339': { ID: '1442-3339', someting:
> 'something', secondArray: {} },   '1442-3340': { ID:
> '1442-3340', something: 'something', secondArray: {} },   '1442-3341':
> { ID: '1442-3341', something: 'something', secondArray: {} } ]

I can access the data via `object['1442-3338']`, **then after storing into the storage and getting it back, which includes JSON.stringify on store and JSON.parse on load, I cannot read the data like that anymore - keys are not recognized.**

Comment: Note: we don't actually call maps associative arrays in JavaScript. You either have objects (like in your code) or `Map` instances. In the case of objects in your code we just call them "objects".

Comment: ` I cannot read the data like that anymore - keys are not recognized.` - without a fully reproducing example it is very hard to help you debug this and I doubt you'll get much useful info. I would consider including a reproducible example.

Comment: okay thanks will do a little later and sure we can call it "object" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer already here on stackoverflow.

**JSON does not allow named keys in arrays.** Thus on transforming the data via JSON.stringify and JSON.parse the array lost the keys.

Had to use a "normal" object instead, which now works fine.

[Link to explanation in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196338/json-stringify-doesnt-work-with-normal-javascript-array)