# stringify doesn't works with my javascript array

Tags: javascript, stringify

I would like to use stringify for encode my javascript array in json

```
params["margin_left"] = "fd";
params["text"] = "df";
params["margin_to_delete"] = "df";

console.info(params);
```

returns (Chrome console) :

```
[margin_left: "fd", text: "df", margin_to_delete: "df"]
```

but when I call :

```
console.info( JSON.stringify(params) );
```

I get

```
[]
```

Anyone knows why ?

Thanx

Comment: Make sure you are defining params as an object `var params = {};`, by the looks of it the bug may be that "params" is defined as an array (thus when stringified being empty since the attributes added via `params["margin_left"]` aren't looked at, only the actual array values)

Comment: That's an object. [And your code does work](http://jsfiddle.net/tR8jT/1/), assuming you declare `params` properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ARZX5/

Comment: How did you declare your array?

Comment: answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089118/convert-a-javascript-associative-array-into-json-object-using-stringify-and-vice

Comment: var params = new Array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make my original comment an answer.

The issue is "params" is being defined as an array, ie.

```
var params = [];
params["margin_left"] = "fd";
params["text"] = "df";
params["margin_to_delete"] = "df";
```

Meaning that when stringify if called, it returns what it has - a blank array. (javascript doesn't support associative arrays, what the above code is actually doing is adding additional attributes to the array object, which do exist, although will be ignored for the purposes of iterating/stringifying)

By making it an object, everything should work as expected

```
var params = {};
params["margin_left"] = "fd";
params["text"] = "df";
params["margin_to_delete"] = "df";
```

Since now when stringify is called, javascript knows its the attributes you want.

Answer (score 0):

As `Carl` pointed, you must define params as object

> var params = {};

Then you can use stringify to convert to JSON String, like this:

```
console.info( JSON.stringify(params) );
```