# How to build a Collection/Model from nested JSON with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm relativly new to Backbone.js

I have a **JSON** like the picture shows ! 
I saw some Answers in relation with Backbone-relational, but still dont get the point!

How can i convert this **JSON** to Backbone.js Collections/Models??

I update with a code but it dont work like expected! i can't see an model when i do :

My Structure is :

[0] : is a collection of models

[clefs] + ... + [Rest] : are collection of models

(clefs) => [0] + ... + [9] : are Models(title contains a string, path too)

Thanks a lot!!

**EDIT(10.01.12) :**

**My Solution :**

```
window.initModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    "title": "",
    "path": ""
  }
});
window.CustomCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: initModel
});
window.Init = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url : function(){
    return  "/api/data.json"      
  },

  parse: function(response) {

    clefs = new CustomCollection();
    clefs.add(response.clefs);        
    this.set({clefs: clefs});

    .....

    rests = new CustomCollection();
    rests.add(response.rests);        
    this.set({rests: rests});
} 
});
```

[this](http://www.deploymentzone.com/2011/08/10/backbone-js-collections-of-models-within-models/) helped me out too!

[image: Nested Array]

Comment: Are you looking to have nested Backbone models/collections as well (this isn't 100% necessary, depending on your requirements). You may be able to get by with just a single Backbone model, with a single object.

Comment: @trouble After having a go with Backbone-Relational I've gone with your solution (overriding parse). With Backbone-Relational certain events 'add' etc weren't firing and were causing problems. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm at work, so I cannot give you a fully coded answer, but the gist is, you can do the following in your top level models to achieve a nested model hierarchy:

```
var AmericasNextTopModel = Backbone.Models.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        this.set({
             clefs: new ClefCollection(this.get('clefs')),
             accidentals: new AccidentalCollection(this.get('accidentals')),
             notes: new NoteCollection(this.get('notes')),
             rests: new RestCollection(this.get('rests'))
        });
    }
});
```

I do not use backbone-relational so I cannot give you an answer regarding that.

Are you making an online sheet music viewer/editor? :D Cool I'd love to see it when you're done.

Comment: Yes i do :D!! i'll tell u when im done! i make an Update in my post about ur answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` method ([see 'reset'](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset)) allows you to pass a JSON array to a collection.
This is the equivalent of a PUT method, replacing the specified collection with the JSON hash.

You can also use the `add` method to add to an existing collection, or pass the JSON hash into the constructor as you create a new collection.

You'll have to do some basic cleaning up of your array to get it in an appropriate format, and then [convert it to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459105/convert-a-multidimensional-javascript-array-to-json)

Comment: huh! I see your points! but this really dont help me construct true Collection of clefs, ..., rest isn't? I really need to have it so like i descripte it! just correct me if im wrong! Thank you!

Comment: My Bad! the picture above is a JSON! sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PHP to grab a feed as JSON since it's on a different domain.  I save those results to a JS variable, and then I just had success using this to get it into my Backbone collection...

```
var feedCollection = new Backbone.Collection();
feedCollection.set(myFeedJSON.nestedObject.nestedArrayIWant);
```